# Help with the analytical solution for the dispersion relation of an elastic wave with wave vector k

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, lattice-model, phonons

I was studying Phonons and Lattice vibrations and came across the equation. I want the mathematical solution for this.
$$M\frac{d^2u_n}{dt^2}=C[u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}-2u_n]$$

from here it is argued that since the atoms vibrate in normal mode all the vibration frequencies are the same hence a solution of the form $e^{i\omega t}$ is assumed. My first doubt is why is the solution assumed to be of this form, from what little mathematics I know, the solution should be of the form $A_1e^{i\omega t}+A_2e^{-i\omega t}$.

So using the above we come down to the next step, feeding this into the double differential we get $$-M{\omega}^2{u_n}=C[u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}-2u_n]$$

Then it says that the solution could be assumed to be a wave vector with a $k$ vector and with an additional phase factor which scales linearly with plane position. This statement allows him/her to write that $$u_n=ue^{inka}$$ where $a$ is the lattice spacing. This is where I completely lose it, can anyone help me with the mathematics underlying the above? I really need it to develop an understanding for the case.

In my attempts to solve$$-M{\omega}^2{u_n}=C[u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}-2u_n]$$, this would be treated as a difference equation of the second order and the solution would be of the form $$u_n={\beta_1}{\lambda_1}^n+{\beta_2}{\lambda_2}^n$$ where $\beta$ and $\lambda$ could be figured out by fitting the corresponding values into the equation. Kindly help me with the solution, someone.

Comment: Are you familiar with [complex wave notation?](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node88.html)  How about coupled oscillations and normal modes?

Comment: Also, I assume that the $u_{n-1}$ terms should have a positive sign in front of them, rather than a negative one.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Yes it should have a negetive sign, no I am not, I'm an engineer so all the physics I've done in my life, I've used maths to ride through it. Could you direct me to the solution mathematically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The lack of the $e^{-i \omega t}$ term is just because we're using [complex wave notation](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node88.html).  If you've ever taken an electrical engineering course, it's the same sort of thing that is used there:  We're using $A e^{i \omega t}$ to stand for $A \cos (\omega t - \delta)$, with the implicit assumption that we're only interested in the real part of the quantities we're writing out.
2. The expression $u_n = u e^{inka}$ **is** of the form you're used to, sort of:
   $$
   u_n = u (e^{ika})^n.$$ 
   This is one of the terms in your general solution to the second-order difference equation, with $\beta_1 = u$ and $\lambda_1 = e^{ika}$.  So it's not as strange a choice as you seem to think it is.

Comment: Ok, so here, instead of having $\lambda$ as the variable to be figured out $k$ becomes that variable, right?